# How turtlesim can use for a real project

Tags: ros, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am able to do following things:

1. Able to run turtlesim node.
2. Able to move turtle using keyboard.
3. Able to move turtle in a specific path using terminal commands.

My doubt is how I can use turtlrsim or other packages in my real project?

I am going to make a basic robot with two motors and some sensors.

Could anyone tell me whether the the ROS software libs/packages are helpful in my robotic project? If yes how can i use it? Is there any useful links for this?

Thankyou

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/70033/how-turtlesim-can-use-for-a-real-project/) by [Sreejith](https://answers.ros.org/users/5533/sreejith/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-07-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Turtlesim covers the basic things like giving velocity to robot and using the tf.
Same way you can use those commands to send commands to your own robot. In your case you can send velocity to a particular topic and use that set of values to generate motor commands.

I hope this helps and please comment if u have any other doubts.

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sreejith](https://answers.ros.org/users/5533/sreejith/) on 2013-07-31**:
Hi, Thank you for support.

Actually I am new to ROS. As per your suggestions I had tried to learn tf: http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials/Introduction%20to%20tf . But i am not getting the logic/flow of using topic to accept velocity. Could you please suggest some links to study about: 1. Sending velocity to topic to control motor. 2. Using a package to control my robot.

Thank you.